# C++ unnamed(anonymous) namespace definition

Tags: c++, namespaces

C++03 Standard 7.3.1.1 [namespace.unnamed] paragraph 1: (and C++11 Standard also use similar definition)

> An *unnamed-namespace-definition* behaves as if it were replaced by
>
> ```
> namespace unique { /* empty body */ }
> using namespace unique;
> namespace unique { namespace-body }
> ```

Why not is it simply following definition?

```
namespace unique { namespace-body }
using namespace unique;
```

Side question: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yct4x9k5.aspx) defines by latter form. Does it violate Standard technically?

Comment: I think this is because in the `namespace-body` you access the entities without extra qualification, which requires that `using namespace unique` be in effect already.

Comment: @mat in the body of a namespace you can always refer to things defined in that namespace without qualification

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I know, I was wondering about the effect of clashes with the surrounding environment though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could not do this anymore

```
namespace { typedef int a; ::a x; }
```

Note that in a subsequent `namespace { ... }`, suddenly you could. This would be horribly inconsistent.

Also notice this case, with two different valid outcomes

```
namespace A { void f(long); }
using namespace A;

namespace { 
  void f(int);
  void g() {
    ::f(0);
  }
}
```

With ISO C++, this calls the `int` version of `f`. With your alternative definition, it calls the `long` version.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out from your answer that what you mean is what I would express as, "the definition in the standard ensures that names declared in the namespace-body can be referred to in the namespace-body by fully-qualifying them using the global namespace. For example ..."