# Is there a difference between "anonymous" and "unnamed" in c++ semantic?

Tags: c++, semantics

I've seen many people regarding them as the same,like [unnamed(anonymous) namespace definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622781/c-unnamedanonymous-namespace-definition)

However,there actually seems to be some difference between them,like [Are “anonymous structs” standard? And, really, what *are* they?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248044/are-anonymous-structs-standard-and-really-what-are-they)

As far as I'm concerned,both of them have no name,it seems hard to me to distinguish them from the semantic.

For example,the `lambda` is a unnamed object of an unnamed class,can we just say `lambda` is a anonymous object of an anonymous class?

Comment: I think that your question is hard to answer. It depends on the context. An unnamed or anonymous class are different, but for namespaces it doesn't matter.

Comment: The word "anonymous" actually means "without a name". They mean the same thing. But, terminology tends to be settled by history, or the standard into using one or the other for different things. Hence *anonymous struct* means a `struct` without a *type name*. We tend to say *unnamed temporary* for compiler generated variables.

Comment: If you search the C++ standard for the term "anonymous namespace" you won't find any matches. If you search for "unnamed namespace" you will find matches. Using the right technical term is important; using terminology that is derived from a pun can be confusing.

Comment: @PeteBecker So there is no term of "anonymous" in the standard,except the "anonymous struct"?

Comment: There are no anonymous structs (that's a Microsoft thing). There are anonymous unions and anonymous bit-fields.