# I have been trying to get an explanation for these two outcomes from the compiler, using quotes from the standard, to no avail so far

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer

[[namespace.unnamed]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.def#namespace.unnamed-1):

> An unnamed-namespace-definition behaves as if it were replaced by
>
> `inline`<sub>*opt*</sub> `namespace` *unique* `{ /* empty body */ }`
> `using namespace unique ;`
> `namespace unique { namespace-body }`
>
> where `inline` appears if and only if it appears in the
> *unnamed-namespace-definition* and all occurrences of *unique* in a translation unit are replaced by the same identifier, and this
> identifier differs from all other identifiers in the translation unit.
> The optional *attribute-specifier-seq* in the
> *unnamed-namespace-definition* appertains to *unique*.

I used the example given by @Johannes Schaub - litb in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13623322/2337207) in SO:

```
namespace A { void f(long); }
using namespace A;

namespace { 
  void f(int);
  void g() {
    ::f(0);
  }
}
```

If I replace the *unnamed-namespace-definition* according to [namespace-unnamed]/1, given above, I get the following code:

```
namespace A { void f(long); }
using namespace A;

namespace unique {}
using namespace unique;
namespace unique {
  void f(int);
  void g() {
    ::f(0);
  }
}

int main(){
    g();
}
```

which shows that the function `g()` calls `unique::f(int)` as can be seen [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96d377b84a47138b).

If I replace the *unnamed-namespace-definition* in the code by

`namespace unique { namespace-body }`
`using namespace unique ;`

I get the following code:

```
namespace A { void f(long); }
using namespace A;

namespace unique {
  void f(int);
  void g() {
    ::f(0);
  }
}
using namespace unique;

int main(){
    g();
}
```

which shows that the function `g()` now calls `A::f(long)` as can be seen [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a476d39c048b4e0b) and confirms what @Johannes Schaub said on his answer. I have been trying to find an explanation for these two different behaviors by the compiler in the Standard, to no avail.

Comment: `::f(0)` explicitly says "search for `f` in the global namespace". At that point, the only entity named `f` visible in the global namespace is `A::f` (since `using namespace unique;` directive, which would allow finding `unique::f` in the global namespace, hasn't been seen yet).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's fine. But why does it find `f(int)`, but does **not** find `f(long)` in the first code?

Comment: It finds both, then overload resolution determines that `f(int)` is a better match for the argument `0` of type `int`. `f(0L)` should call `A::f(long)`

Comment: Great answer. I never thought this would be so easy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can go ahead and answer the question yourself. That would allow the post to be resolved.